# Heroku react dev Dockefile with permissions issue

Tags: reactjs, docker, heroku

I'm deploying a dockerized React app to Heroku (via Travis CI, but I don't think that matters). Heroku [recommends not running as root](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#run-the-image-as-a-non-root-user) in dev, since in production they don't run as root, by adding

```
RUN adduser -D myuser
USER myuser
```

However, this Dockerfile, which was running fine until I added that chunk (or similar), now fails:

```
# pull official base image
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install app dependencies
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install && npm audit fix --force

# add app
COPY . ./

### ------------------- works without this section ------------------- ###
RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S appuser && \ 
    adduser -u 1001 -S appuser -G appuser && \
    chown -R appuser ./
USER appuser
### ------------------------------------------------------------------ ###

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Docker Desktop outputs:

```
> react-scripts start
ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.18.0.2/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...

Failed to compile.

EACCES: permission denied, open '/app/.eslintcache'
```

It all points to issues with users and permissions but I don't know if my syntax is wrong or if this is just not what Heroku is actually recommending, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Try moving user creation to the start of the dockerfile. --- Does the directory `/app` already exist? If not, it is created automatically, but with `root:root` as owner (ignoring the current `USER`). The way to fix this would be to `COPY` a (n empty) folder with `--chown 1001:1001`, or to `mdir` the folder as `USER 1001` (provided `mkdir` is available in the image).

Comment: @Turing85 Heroku recommends creating and activating the user "immediately before CMD". But to follow your advice, when I move it up, the `npm install` command says I don't have access to `/app`. If I try to `chown` or `mkdir` the `app` folder, I get `Operation not permitted` or `Permission denied`.

Comment: Then create the user, `RUN chown -R 1001:1001 /app`, followed by `USER 1001`. This should yield the expected result.

Comment: @Turing85 Nah, unfortunately I'm trying `RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S appuser && 
    adduser -u 1001 -S appuser -G appuser && mkdir /app && chown -R 1001:1001 /app` followed by the USER command, but still that same that `/app/.eslintcache` permission denied error. When I `ls -al` inside the container, `.eslintcache` seems to still belong to root.

Comment: Can you share your project, e.g. via github?

Comment: @Turing85 Thanks for offering all this help. I could potentially share the repo but it really just is a create react app and this Dockerfile (ran with docker-compose). And everything actually just works fine if I just omit all this user stuff and just run with root. This is just me trying to heed Heroku's warning to run as non-root :/

Comment: [you really should not run containers as root though](https://medium.com/@mccode/processes-in-containers-should-not-run-as-root-2feae3f0df3b)....

Comment: @Turing85 ah, well all the more reason. I really do want to follow the best practices, especially regarding security, so I want to figure this out. What's weird is that the [tutorial](https://mherman.org/blog/dockerizing-a-react-app/) I copied the Dockerfile from didn't take this into account.

Comment: @Turing85 I believe I've found the issue and it relates to the volumes I was declaring in docker-compose.yml. Going to edit my question with what I think I found was the problem.

Comment: Don't forget that you can answer your own question if you solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still new to Docker so I don't know if this is all conceptually correct but I think I solved it.

First, I thought I got it to work by removing the `.:/app` volume in docker-compose.yml but then I realized that, by de-linking the host with the image, I lost React's hot reloading. So docker-compose.yml has to look like this:

```
version: '3.8'

services:

  frontend:
    container_name: poeclient
    stdin_open: true
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - '.:/app'            # required for hot reloading, needs Dockerfile user = local user
      - '/app/node_modules'
    ports:
      - 3001:3000
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
```

Also, because my local user id is 1000 I have to use that id in the Dockerfile. Since that Apline image comes with a user named 'node' with that id, I don't have to create one in the Dockerfile:

```
# pull official base image
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install app dependencies
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install && npm audit fix --force

# add app with non root owner
COPY . ./

# switch to non-root user 'node' (uid: 1000), which comes with alpine image
# switch now instead of earlier to allow for other commands to be run as root
# for react hot reloading needs to be 1000 because host user is also 1000
USER 1000

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Despite all this, the .eslintcache file still showed up in the container as belonging to root. So one last thing that was needed was, in my local folder, to `chown` the .eslintcache from root to my local user (1000) and then the Dockerfile was able to show an .eslintcache that belonged to 1000.